# .htaccess basic mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I am only just starting to learn how to rewrite urls with the .htaccess file.

How would I change:

http://www.url.net/games/game_one.php

into this:

http://www.url.net/games/game-one/

This is what I have been trying

```
RewriteRule    ^/games/game-one.php    ^/games/game-one/    [NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule    ^/games/game_one.php    ^/games/game-one/ [NC,L]

Comment: regular expressions is like alien speak to me :(

Comment: We must all study the mystic runes of the aliens... they have power!

Comment: I just wish the aliens didn't speak in random characters o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want people to use */games/game-one/* explicitly, you have to rewrite so that it requests */game/game-one.php*. So the opposite way around than you have it in your question.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^games/game-one/$ /games/game-one.php
```

If you want to rewrite other URL's too, then you'd need to use a technique similar to the prior answer.

Comment: Oh hehe, yeah, she probably has it backwards. Was focusing on explaining regexs and didn't even notice :)

Comment: @Gus It's a tricky subject to describe (even when you don't speak alien!)

Comment: @AmyNeville Pleasure. There are some good regex guides/cheatsheets on the web. Worth hunting down as well as asking questions on SO!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(/games/game-one)\.php $1/
```

What that says is match anything starting with /games/game-one and remember the first part of that match, then replace it with the first part (capturing group in regex speak), and a slash character. Note that to match a period character you must precede it with a \ since `.` is a special character that means "any character" (at least if you care to avoid matching any character).

Comment: yes I see. Hmm doesn't work though on my site. I'll give you a +1 anyway for helping :)

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteEngine on` directive?