# Error 404 on rewriting url in file .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site with Joomla with Hosting Aruba

I tried to test the mod rewrite  of the .htaccess with this line :

```
RewriteRule ^prova.html$ /test.html [R=301,L]
```

And it works, the existing page is

- http://www.musicamatrimonio.com/prova.html

and the destination url

- http://www.musicamatrimonio.com/test.html.

The problem is that the destination url has error 404 and hasn't the content of the page prova.html

Can you help me??

Comment: I think you don't quite understand how rewrite works. What exactly are you trying to do? If you use redirection, R flag, then it will redirect to the URL you say. It will not check to see if that file exists or not before doing so.

Comment: Yes tks, my target is display the page prova.html with the url test.html

Comment: Not as redirect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess basic mod rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490293/htaccess-basic-mod-rewrite)